# How to close dropdown on onchange event of selector In IOS 6.0(Iphone) by jquery for Hybrid application

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ibm-mobilefirst

I am working on hybrid application with worklight. I am using Javascript code. 
Tapping on select control, a native dropdown pops out. Now I have bound onchange event on this select. so when I chose any option event gets fired but dropdown doesn't fadeout until I tap on done button. I have used ('select').blur() to overcome and it is working fine for android but not for IOS 6.0(Iphone).So I want fadeout of dropdown with onchange.

Code:

```
<select id="myID" onchange="myFun()">;

function myFun(){
    $('select').blur();
}

or

function myFun(){
    $('#myID').blur();
}
```

What are the possible soultions for it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to read this document from Apple:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html